# Extending session timeout in PHP via the .htaccess

Tags: php, session, timeout

I want to up the time my users will stay logged into my site without getting automatically logged out after a period of inactivity. I'm tracking the logged in status using PHP sessions.

How can I set this, I'm trying to control this from my .htaccess file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

Comment: For anyone finding this in 2012 or beyond. There is a wealth of here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes that you might want to read first! (read the top answer)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<strike>You can't do that from the htaccess file but</strike> You can change this line in your `php.ini` file.

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
```

Update: it seems to be possible, so i stand corrected

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 3600
```

I haven't tried this out though.

Comment: Also take into account the max cookie lifetime.

Answer (score 7):

You could also try changing the value at runtime using [`ini_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php):

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '3600');
```

Comment: can we do it in a shared hosting?