# Two PHPSESSID cookies is being set for some users

Tags: php, apache, session

On some browsers, we have two PHPSESSIDs.

- One PHPSESSID is not set by me anywhere in my script
- It has HOST (instead of DOMAIN for the PHPSESSID I set) as www.mywebsite.com
- I have tried deleting it using setcookie: `setcookie ("PHPSESSID", $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'], time() - 864000, '/', 'www.mywebsite.com');` but this fails.
- An attempt to delete cookie using: `setcookie ("PHPSESSID", $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'], time() - 864000, '/');` results in the PHPSESSID I set being deleted.
- I have tried using `session_name` to rename the SESSION I set. This works but crashed my server severally after some minutes.

As a result of the double PHPSESSID, some users cannot login.

How do I fix this as I am out of options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete PHPSESSID on client computers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517997/how-do-i-delete-phpsessid-on-client-computers)

Comment: @Vineet1982 OP is the same! :)

Comment: @Ogugua Same like your previous question, you are not giving the proper description how your login is related to `PHPSESSID` and how 2 `PHPSESSID` impacts one another. Someone can better solve your problem, if you do so!

Answer (score 0):

```
unset($_COOKIE['name']);
@setcookie('name', null, -1, '/', $hostForCookies);
```

try remove cookies like this...

Comment: This may not solve my problem. Remember, I need one of the PHPSESSID cookies for login to work properly.