# how to delete all cookies of all paths which generated by website

Tags: php, cookies

I by mistake generate one cookie. which is now affecting my website. it generates in all the path of my website. because I set it up in a header file.

Now I want to delete that cookie once for all the paths.

`setcookie('PHPSESSID','xyz',time()+800000);`

I can able to delete only one cookie which set on path `/` but I can't delete all other cookies which set on different paths from `logout.php` file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete PHPSESSID on client computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517997/how-do-i-delete-phpsessid-on-client-computers)

Comment: @rkeet i tried the solutions but not working properly. i can only delete the cookie which is in path `/` i also wan to delete all cookies which are on different paths

Answer (score 0):

When deleting a cookie you should assure that the expiration date is in the past, to trigger the removal mechanism in your browser.

```
setcookie('PHPSESSID','',time()-3600);
```

Comment: i already mentioned that i can able to delete the cookie which in path `/` but i want to delete all the cookies which are on different paths. like `/abc`, `/xyz/123` etc

Comment: You can not get the cookies path from the user browser. For example, you can use your routing table or your sitemap to find cookies to delete.